# How to create a Recylerview that can circulate 360 degree?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, circular-list

**How we can create a Circular RecylerView? Like this**

Are there libraries for this, in which we can create circular recylerview like this?
Kindly let me know if you have designed a recylerview like this.
Thanks in advance
Arfa Ejaz

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZrW2.png

Comment: Please verify whether that is even a `RecyclerView`? That image might be some static views...

Comment: if its a recylerview can we create like this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own implementation, if you don't have a specific use-case you can just use a library, for instance [CircularRecyclerView](https://github.com/Palatis/CircularRecyclerView).
Is a straightforward implementation.

But, if you want to make it custom, you can follow this tutorial [circule-menu](http://www.tutorialsee.com/circle-menu/how-make-design-circle-menu-example-android) that is also good and I guess it fits on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPager and RecyclerView. Within each ViewPager screen add a Recycler View. This way you can scroll vertically as well Horizontally.